# Auto save file from one local disk to another

Tags: windows

I have two local drives and one .xlsx file that dropped every day on local drive1.

Is that possible to auto save that file on local drive2 after it appeared on the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a text file with following content and save it as Batch File(e.g.: copier.bat):

```
xcopy  "e:\source_folder\source.xls" "f:\destination_folder" /e /i /h
```

Here,
xcopy is a basic copy command 
So, when you double click copier.bat your excel file will be copied.
It can be used to copy multiple Files and Folders as well.